# Why is my correct connection attempt failing under apache2 but not under cli?

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, mysqli, apache2

I have a live hosting server where Apache and MySQL are installed. If I run on cli

```
mysql -u <username> -p
```

and then type in the password, I log in successfully. If I do

```
mysql -u <username> -h localhost -p -P 3306 <dbname>
```

and then type in the password, then I successfully connect to MySQL and the database is successfully selected as well. So, I have implemented a small php file, which looks like this:

```
<?php

$result = mysqli_real_connect(mysqli_init(), 'localhost', '<username>', '<password>', '<databasename>', 3306);

echo var_dump($result);
```

and I run it via cli as:

```
php mytestfile.php
```

and it successfully connects to the database and shows the result of

> bool(true)

However, if I attempt to load the very same file from the web-browser, then the result is

> bool(false)

which clearly indicates that the very same attempt to connect from cli works, while attempting to connect via apache2 fails. Tried:

## 1. Restarting Apache

```
service apache2 restart
```

## 2. Restarting MySQL

```
service restart apache2
```

## 3. Using the very same ini file

```
mv /etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini /etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini_old

cp /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini /etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini

service restart apache2
```

## 4. Searching for answers online

I have found some selinux-related answers that were saying that we need to allow network access to MySQL, however, they seemed unrelated to this problem, because I'm connecting to localhost, so MySQL runs on the same machine as Apache.

## 5. Comparing socket file paths

mysql.sock is located on the exact same place in both php.ini

## 6. Comparing 20-mysqli.ini

They were identical

## 7. Finding out who the script executing user was

```
get_current_user()
```

yields root both when I execute it from cli and from Apache.

## Note

This is not a new install. This worked correctly long-term, but during the week, while testing some curl-related logic I have been shocked to see that my hobby project is broken live. So, decided to investigate the issue during the weekend. However, all my tries were failing. What might be the problem?

Note, this is not an opinionated question, I look for things to check besides the things that I have already checked and listed above. An answer is objectively correct, if it contains a list of one or more elements that may be causing the issue I am experiencing. The answer which contains the most detailed description and the highest number of possible problems (except those that I was already checking for) will be chosen, as long as the specific problem I have is among the problems listed.

I do not intend to reinstall the operating system, Apache or MySQL. I know that if I purge everything from the server and reinstall, then this will work. However, since this is a hobby project, I can allow it to be down indefinitely in order to experiment and find out what the issue is.

The error message I get is **Permission Denied**.

Comment: What error code do you get when trying to connect using apache? ```mysqli_connect_errno()```

Comment: [mysqli\_fetch\_assoc() expects parameter / Call to a member function bind\_param() errors. How to get the actual mysql error and fix it?](//stackoverflow.com/q/22662488) and [How can I get useful error messages in PHP?](//stackoverflow.com/q/845021)

Comment: @EnricoDias Permission Denied

Comment: @mario I get permission denied as an error message, forgot to mention in the question. Will edit it to reflect the problem.

Comment: @LajosArpad you can get the permission denied error with a wrong username/password or if the mysql is configured to refuse connections from a specific host. See if that helps: https://linuxize.com/post/mysql-remote-access/

Comment: Full error message, PHP SAPI, systemd/cgroups, apparmor/selinux, GRANT table, etc. [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](//stackoverflow.com/a/32681786)

Comment: @EnricoDias please read the question. It is mentioned there that the very same credentials work with cli and not with apache and that the same user is involved and the same host.

Comment: @mario the full error is Permission Denied. It is the exact value of connect_error.

Comment: @LajosArpad I did read the question, but if the ```bind-address``` is not correctly configured in your mysql config or if your grant table isn't allowing for connections from a specific host, even if it's localhost, you may get this error.

Comment: Note that you can still connect to mysql using the cli even if it's not configured to listen in any address.

Comment: @EnricoDias I ran both direct connection from cli and a PHP script from cli. When I run my PHP script through cli, then I am connecting to MySQL from the very same host with the very same user and very same credentials, using the very same port as the one used by Apache.

Comment: @EnricoDias also, the connection to database was working via Apache for many months, so something went broken on a configuration which worked previously correctly.

Comment: I see the question was voted to be closed because of lack of details. I do not know what detail is missing for someone to ponder about possible causes of this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve the problem, but I'm not 100% sure that I correctly determined what the problem was. Basically, in order to fix the issue, and knowing that modernizing will never hurt (especially when things are already broken), I have upgraded PHP to version 8.0, but then the/some problem still persisted, albeit a different error message was provided, which was saying that some folder was missing. Then, I changed the host in the connection settings from **localhost** to **127.0.0.1** and it works.

So, my best guess about what the problem might have been is that for some reason **localhost** has stopped being a correct host name for some reason, while **127.0.0.1** is a correct host name, so a step that I have definitely missed during the investigation was to check what the allowed hosts are, because I assumed that this was unchanged. However, even though I strongly suspect that this was the solution to the problem, I do not factually know whether that's the case. Before upgrading PHP from 7.4 to 8.0 the error message when attempting to run things via Apache was **Permission Denied** and running the very same PHP script via cli was working impeccably. After upgrading PHP to version 8.0, the same script responded with an error message that stated that some folder was missing, without telling me what that folder was, yet, changing hostname from **localhost** to **127.0.0.1** did the trick.

Steps I have taken in order to resolve the problem, inspired by https://www.tecmint.com/install-php-8-on-ubuntu/ :

```
apt update
apt upgrade
apt install  ca-certificates apt-transport-https software-properties-common
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
apt update
apt install php8.0 libapache2-mod-php8.0
apt install php8.0-mysqli
```

**Note**: I was doing these operations with the root user. If you are doing an upgrade with another user, then you will need to do so with a sudoer and you might need a `sudo` keyword before the operations above.

Now, running `php -v` yields

[image]

However, the trick was to change my settings file so it will use **127.0.0.1** as the host value instead of **localhost**. This is extremely strange for me, since the very same settings were working properly before, only I have access to the database and I certainly did not change the allowed connections and the fact that via cli I was able to connect to localhost added a lot to the strangeness.

So, all in all, due to the fact that my experiments yielded results earlier than getting any useful answers or hints, I decided to write an answer on my own. However, I am happy to accept an answer which contains a better understanding of the issue than my own, since this answer admittedly does not contain an explanation of what the issue is and hence, this answer is only acceptable until someone comes up with a proper explanation of what might have happened that caused the issue that's now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my previous comments, your mysql wasn't allowing incoming connections from that specific host. "localhost" is different from 127.0.0.1. "localhost" means local socket connection while 127.0.0.1 is treated as TCP/IP.

Executing a php script directly in the cli might yield different results than executing it with apache. One execution could use try to use local socket connections while the other tries to use TCP. The way apache executes php (ie. mod_php, php_fpm, etc) may also play a role in this, even if they both use the same php.ini.

As for why it was working before and stopped suddenly; something probably changed without you notice it. I've experienced issues mysql/mariadb config tables before and even filled a bug report, although not directly related to your issue.

Comment: And why did it work when I ran the same PHP script from CLI that was connecting via localhost?

Comment: "Executing a php script directly in the cli might yield different results than executing it with apache." Yes, but they both connected using "localhost" as the host.

Comment: The php executable is probably different and apache can overwrite php.ini configs during execution time. There are probably other differences since some php functions seem to recognize when the code is being executed in the cli or by a http server.

Comment: The executable PHP file was the very same in both cases. It was connecting to MySQL using "localhost" as the host. If "localhost" was incorrect host for MySQL, then connecting to MySQL via "localhost" should have failed both when it was attempted via Apache and when it was attempted by running a PHP via cli. Besides that, the direct connection to MySQL via cli like `mysql -u <username> -h localhost -p -P 3306 <dbname>` should have failed. It didn't fail, therefore we are still missing something. I would like to accept your answer, but the issue is still unclear.

Comment: The php that apache uses in your system is located in ```/etc/php/7.4/apache2/``` with several other config files. You mentioned that you copied the php.ini to the cli folder and nothing else. Something in your setup is probably preventing the php executed by apache from using sockets, either a config in apache or in other files inside the php folder used by apache. Either way, it's good to remember that 127.* and localhost behaves differently.

Comment: Yes, there are two PHPs and something was preventing Apache from processing the requests to MySQL. I'm not sure whether it's the PHP installation or Apache, however, as you pointed out, the ini file of cli was temporarily used for Apache as well for the purpose of the experiment with similar results. I'm not sure what might have been the solution, however, host being "localhost" was not a problem according to my findings. However, after upgrading to PHP 8.0, localhost as a host no longer worked in cli nor in apache.

Comment: So at that point I changed it to 127.0.0.1 and it worked. But before that, under cli, the host "localhost" was working perfectly both if I ran a PHP command or I connected directly to MySQL via the terminal. So I'm still unsure what the problem was. And (un)fortunately, since the problem no longer reproduces due to the measures I have taken, I'm not sure whether we will ever find out what it was.